# Entity Framework 4 View Generation - Embedding files question and what about Source Control (TFS)

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I am pre-generating views for a class project with an Entity Framework 4 edmx that is consumed by an asp.net application.

The resources I have used as reference are:

http://blog.willbeattie.net/2010/04/pre-generating-views-in-entity.html
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx

The problem I am having relates to source control and also brings up another question about embedding the csdl/msl/ssdl files into the assembly. The articles above dictate the need to embed the aforementioned resources into the assembly by including them in the project and setting the files to be embedded.

But that leads me to wonder, since these files are being generated on build and copied over after, wouldn't the assembly always contain the *last* version of the csdl/msl/ssdl files? Because these files are generated on build and marked in the project to be embedded it would seem the files are embedded into the assembly are the ones previously generated on the previous build.

The heart of my issue concerns source control. If I include the csdl/msl/ssdl files in source control every time the project is taken down it won't build because these files will be marked as read only and Visual Studio will error when the post build process tries to copy the newly generated files over the files brought down from source control which are marked as read only. Due to the fact that these files are required for building the project but not generated until after the project is built I'm not currently seeing how I can successfully not check the csdl/msl/ssdl files into source control only keeping the reference to them in the project file there. This works for the Views.cs file which is generated on pre build but not the csdl/msl/ssdl files that are copied over on post build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wouldn't the assembly always contain the last version of the csdl/msl/ssdl files?

It depends on your build order.

If you just include the files and generate views after build, then yes, you get the previous files. One fix is to build twice when you change your schemata, which isn't usually very often.

Another fix would be to use a resource editor to overwrite the stored files after build.

Not sure how to fix your source control; we use non-locking source control, which makes this a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

I create my *.views.cs via a t4 template that I found on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx).

This negates all the pre/post build events and simplified the process. Also there is no problem with source control.
The tt file is totally generic and can be reused for any edmx by simply renaming it.

Hope it helps...